# How to configure OpenPorts option for New-AzureRmVm to create VM without default network security group RDP port(3389,5985).

Tags: azure, powershell

I'd like to create Windows Server VM which has source filtered RDP port using Powershell.

[New-AzureRmVM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.compute/new-azurermvm?view=azurermps-6.13.0) and [Add-AzureRmNetworkSecurityRuleConfig](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.network/add-azurermnetworksecurityruleconfig?view=azurermps-6.13.0) partially work for me.

New-AzureRmVM create VM with nsg rule for default RDP port which allow any source. I have to delete them after the script run.

I tried to set -OpenPorts option to $null or None.

Is this possible? Or, any other method to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it seems you cannot delete the RDP NGS rule through setting the -OpenPorts to $null or None when you create the VM using PowerShell command New-AzureRmVM.

> -OpenPorts
>
> A list of ports to open on the network security group (NSG) for the created VM. The default value depends on the type of image
> chosen (i.e., Windows: 3389, 5985 and Linux: 22).

When you create the windows VM, the default port is opened according to the image type. But you can change the NSG rule to filter the traffic when you creating.

```
# Create an inbound network security group rule for port 3389
$nsgRuleRDP = New-AzureRmNetworkSecurityRuleConfig -Name myNetworkSecurityGroupRuleRDP  -Protocol Tcp `
  -Direction Inbound -Priority 1000 -SourceAddressPrefix * -SourcePortRange * -DestinationAddressPrefix * `
  -DestinationPortRange 3389 -Access Allow

# Create a network security group
$nsg = New-AzureRmNetworkSecurityGroup -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -Location $location `
  -Name myNetworkSecurityGroup -SecurityRules $nsgRuleRDP
```

Set the `-SourceAddressPrefix`, `-SourcePortRange`, `-DestinationAddressPrefix` and the `-Access` as you want to filter the traffic. For more details, see [Create a fully configured virtual machine with PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/scripts/virtual-machines-windows-powershell-sample-create-vm?toc=%2Fpowershell%2Fmodule%2Ftoc.json).

Answer (score 0):

You can change Azure VM default RDP port. For more details, please refer to the [blog](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/drew/2017/04/14/1195/).

```
Write-host "What Port would you like to set for RDP: " -ForegroundColor Yellow -NoNewline;$RDPPort = Read-Host

Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server\WinStations\RDP-TCP\" -Name PortNumber -Value $RDPPort

New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "RDP HighPort" -Direction Inbound –LocalPort $RDPPort -Protocol TCP -Action Allow
```

Comment: This will change VM firewall RDP port. I'd like to change network security rule, not firewall rule.